# Can I get AngularJS to use different controllers for Facebook OpenGraph scraper?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, .htaccess, facebook-opengraph

I have an AngularJS application that is served up using [**http-server**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

I want my the meta-tags (`og:title`, `og:description`, `og:image`) to be populated dynamically for [**Facebook**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and other scrapers (like Slack) to post rich-links on social media sites. However, it is tricky because those scrapers do their scraping of the original HTML page before angular dynamically inserts the proper values. So the scrapers see the placeholder values.

One solution to this problem is described [**here**](https://rck.ms/angular-handlebars-open-graph-facebook-share/). Basically: feed the scraper-bots static HTML with desired `og` fields already populated. I would like to do that. But unlike that author, I'm not using apache. In `http-server` there is no .htaccess file that I'm aware of.m

I use [**UI-Router**](https://ui-router.github.io/) and `$state-provider` to handle the URLs provided to my application like this:

```
  $stateProvider.state('splash',
      {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'html/splash.html',
          controller: 'SplashCtrl',
          data: {
              meta: {
                'title': 'My Title',
                'description': 'My Description'
              }
          }
      }
  );
```

Is there some way I can create a state such that scraper-bots will be sent to a different controller than normal human users using a web-browser? How?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with one of our web applications. We solved it by making some of the following changes. It involves making changes in both the frontend and the backend.

The first problem in this case is, angular uses `/#/` as the separator to determine routes and history. If you share a link that has the `#` char, anything after it will be ignored and not be sent to the server. To dynamically generate metadata for social sites, we need the part after `#`. So, we eliminate the `/#/` altogether.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .config(function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  // 
    });
```

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Setting this will make sure your URLs will now change from `http://app_host/#/my_url` to `http://app_host/my_url`

Just to make sure AngularJS now understands how to interpret its routes, you need to set the base path for your application

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="/">
    </head>
</html>
```

With this config, your sharable links now will land on your backend server, where you always return the same index.html file, but with dynamic meta tags based on the extra path params you receive.

Comment: Here is where we are using it:
Home page: http://arivu.org.in/
Specific Page: http://arivu.org.in/view/5745060998021120/video/5098651508539392
If you use the facebook debugger, you should be able to see different metadata for these links, even though they are just the same app.

Comment: I just don't see how this is the solution to my question. You have explained how to eliminate the `#/` in the URL, and I have done that. However nowhere do I see you directing the request to different controllers if the visitor is a bot or not. Everything you are doing here is purely AngularJS. So it is Front-end code. Nothing here directs it to the back-end server. What am I missing?

Comment: These are the things you need to do on the frontend. Backend I can't comment without knowing the technology you are using to handle the requests. With these changes - your requests for different pages land on your backend - where you have to decide what to populate for the meta tags and always return your index.html (or equivalent). You need to understand that you can't achieve the dynamic meta tags with frontend changes alone. Bots don't execute your page, they just read whatever is provided to it, so it's the responsibility of your backend to put appropriate tags based on the `path`.